# How can I format Powershell Get-Culture cmdlet output?

Tags: powershell

I have a large text file of horribly capitalized text and duplicates. I used PowerShell to remove duplicates and to make everything lowercase. Now, I'd like to capitalize the first letter of each word. To do this, I used the following;

```
$var = (Get-Content "C:\FilePath")
(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($Var)
```

This works like  a charm, BUT the output goes from being a string on each line to a huge blob of run on text. I am at a loss to format this, Select-Object, Sort, Export-Csv all failed to help me. Is there someway to keep the strings from blobing together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$var` is an array, so you can process it as an array:

```
$var = (Get-Content "C:\FilePath")
foreach ($line in $var) {
    (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($line)
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Though it did through an empty pipe error. I think that's because I can't capture an output stream? Anyway, That was fixed by making it a variable. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons I would save a reference once to the text info (insted of calling Get-Culture for each line) and use it inside a foreach loop:

```
$textInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
Get-Content C:\FilePath | Foreach-Object {  $textInfo.ToTitleCase($_) }
```